# WampServer Site URL not working without localhost prefix

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, wampserver

I was using Wamp 2.4 but had to uninstall it and install 3.0.6 alongside the 3.0.8 update. Everything works fine by selecting the Add localhost option in the wamp tray setting and stating /mysitefolder/ in the .htaccess and http//localhost/mysitefolder in the config files of the application.

But I like the idea of using virtualhost especially with the GUI form provided to create VH via an interface. I created a VH of a project I was working on prior to version 3.0.6 installation. Now I edited the .htaccess and config file of codeigniter code I was working with so that rather than localhost/mysitefolder as default I can now navigate to http://mysitefolder.

The problem: pointing to http://mysitefolder displays rightly but clicking  any of the links to subpages results in the same browser error:

> "Not Found The requested URL /mysitefolder.txt/index.php was not found
>   on this server. Apache/2.4.23 (Win32) PHP/5.6.25 Server at
>   mysitefolder Port 80"

First I don't understand where the .txt extension is emanating from and I don't know how to go about fixing this.

Working with Windows 8.1, Apache 2.4.3 with mod rewrite selected.

Kindly advise.

APACH VHOST FILe

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp/www
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName financejobs
    ServerAlias financejobs
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/financejobs"
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/financejobs">
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Codeigniter Application HTACCSS (for financejobs)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /financejobs/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^jp_sys.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^jp_app.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule> 
Options -Indexes
```

Comment: Could you add your .htaccess and your vhost?

Comment: @AndrewOsenga I've added those

Comment: Try changing `RewriteBase /financejobs/` to `RewriteBase /`

Comment: @Condorcho didn't notice that, thanks worked! How do I mark this as answered?

Comment: Cool, glad to help.

Comment: How do I mark this as answered?

Comment: There, i posted it as an answer, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer:

Try changing `RewriteBase /financejobs/` to `RewriteBase /`